# Enforce unique rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-error-1071

I have a table in `MySQL` that has 3 fields and I want to enforce uniqueness among two of the fields.  Here is the table `DDL`:

```
CREATE TABLE `CLIENT_NAMES` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`CLIENT_NAME` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`OWNER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `ID` field is a surrogate key (this table is being loaded with ETL).
The `CLIENT_NAME` is a field that contains names of clients
The `OWNER_ID` is an id indicates a clients owner.

I thought I could enforce this with a unique index on `CLIENT_NAME` and `OWNER_ID`,

```
ALTER TABLE `DW`.`CLIENT_NAMES` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX enforce_unique_idx(`CLIENT_NAME`, `OWNER_ID`);
```

but MySQL gives me an error:

> Error executing SQL commands to update table.
>   Specified key was too long; max key length is 765 bytes (error 1071)

Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL cannot enforce uniqueness on keys that are longer than 765 bytes (and apparently 500 UTF8 characters can surpass this limit).

1. Does CLIENT_NAME really need to be 500 characters long? Seems a bit excessive.
2. Add a new (shorter) column that is hash(CLIENT_NAME). Get MySQL to enforce uniqueness on that hash instead.

Comment: Unicode is a variable length encoding. Characters can be one to four bytes in size and only the original 128 ASCII characters are encoded in one byte.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at CONSTRAINT ... UNIQUE?

Answer (score 0):

Something seems a bit odd about this table; I would actually think about refactoring it. What do ID and OWNER_ID refer to, and what is the relationship between them?

Would it make sense to have

```
CREATE TABLE `CLIENTS` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`CLIENT_NAME` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
# other client fields - address, phone, whatever
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `CLIENTS_OWNERS` (
`CLIENT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`OWNER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`CLIENT_ID`,`OWNER_ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would really avoid adding a unique key like that on a 500 character string. It's much more efficient to enforce uniqueness on two ints, plus an id in a table should really refer to something that needs an id; in your version, the `ID` field seems to identify just the client/owner relationship, which really doesn't need a separate id, since it's just a mapping.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/17/max-key-length-in-mysql/).  For the UTF8 charset, MySQL may use up to 3 bytes per character.  CLIENT_NAME is 3 x 500 = 1500 bytes.  Shorten `CLIENT_NAME` to 250.

*later:* +1 to creating a hash of the name and using that as the key.

Comment: Saying that UTF-8 uses 3 bytes/char is wrong. As the page yourself pointed out said, it can take UP TO that value, and what makes it impossible to use on MySQL is the pessimistic approach.